# Getting Jenkins Build Results through HTTP Get request

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to get test results from a Jenkins job and was wondering if it was possible to get the json results by making a GET request (e.g. to a certain job: `JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build/api/json`) while not logged into the Jenkins server.

I am having trouble understanding how you can send all the how do you pass the authentication information in the API call (e.g. API token / password, username).

I know the Jenkins CLI is an option, but I would prefer not to use it if possible.

To be clear, when logged in on my computer, calls to `JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build/api/json` yield the build results, but when I log out, the link takes me to the log in page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure your credentials and give read access for anonymous or pass your user/password in your request:

```
curl --user username:password jenkins_url/job/job_name/build_number/api/json
```

The same but using api_token:

```
curl --user username:api_token jenkins_url/job/job_name/build_number/api/json
```

If you pass also`?pretty=true` parameter, you should see something like this:

```
{
   "actions" : [
     {
       "parameters" : [
         ...
      }
   ],
  ...
  "building" : false,
  "description" : null,
  "displayName" : "#36",
  "duration" : 1936,
  "estimatedDuration" : 2020,
  "number" : 36,
  "queueId" : 224,
}
```